# Extracting specific items from a list with year 2000 by using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I have a huge list of data in the given format below.I need to  extract all the data with year 2000. How ever when i try to implement it, I get an error 'invalid literal for int() with base 10:'year''

This is the code i used to extract the data. and It doesnt seems to work.

```
['title','country','year','val',]
['bm','china','1987','2200']
['bm','japan','2000','1600']
['bm','germany','2000','70']
#it doesnt seem to work 
new=[]
for i in list:
    if i[2]==2000:
       new.append(int(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
new = [i for i in list[1:] if '2000' == i[2]]
```

'list' is a keyword in python. Its best practice to avoid using it in code.

Comment: Note that this will fail for cases such as `['bm','japan','02000','1600']` or `['bm','japan','2000.0','1600']`

Comment: Yes, the sample provides is small. In that case, one should clean data first before processing it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting literal error , is because your code is trying to convert String 'Year' to int. Remove the 1st list ( headers ) from the conversion.

Comment: As per the statement in question 
```i get this error invalid literal for int() with base 10:'year' ````
. So its the 'year' string which is giving him the error

Answer (score 0):

1st, you should **NOT** be naming your variable as `list`, because `list` is a built-in data type of Python. You should **NOT** name your variables and functions the same as the built-in types and functions. Use something else, ex. `mylist`.

2nd, it's probably not working because you are including the list `['title', 'country', 'year', 'val',]` in the loop, and `i[2]` will be `"year"` and when your tried to cast `"year"` (a string) to an int, it raised the error.

One option is to skip the 1st list that looks like a header.

```py
mylist = [
    ['title','country','year','val',],
    ['bm','china','1987','2200'],
    ['bm','japan','2000','1600'],
    ['bm','germany','2000','70']
]

new=[]
for i in mylist[1:]:
    year = int(i[2])
    if year==2000:
       new.append(i)
print(new)
# [['bm', 'japan', '2000', '1600'], ['bm', 'germany', '2000', '70']]
```

Another option if you don't know whether the `i[2]` will be a valid integer value, is to `try` to cast it and then just skip it if it fails:

```py
mylist = [
    ['title','country','year','val',],
    ['bm','china','1987','2200'],
    ['bm','japan','2000','1600'],
    ['bm','germany','2000','70']
]

new=[]
for i in mylist:
    try:
        year = int(i[2])
    except ValueError:
        continue
    if year==2000:
        new.append(i)
print(new)
# [['bm', 'japan', '2000', '1600'], ['bm', 'germany', '2000', '70']]
```